# How to bind datagrid with two itemsSource in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have something like this in my xaml

```
<DataGrid  Name="dgDisplay" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="dgItemCode" Width="100" Header="Barcode" Binding="{Binding ItemCode}" />
           <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="dgItemName" Width="200" Header="Item Name" Binding="{Binding ItemName}" />
           <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="dgItemPrice" Width="100" Header="Item Price" Binding="{Binding ItemPrice, StringFormat=RM {0}}" />
           <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="dgQuantity" Width="150" Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

      <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate >
         <DataTemplate  x:Name="dtItemDisplay"  >
           <StackPanel  Name="spItemDisplay2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" >
              <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="Discount: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                 <TextBox KeyDown="TxtDisc_KeyDown"  x:Name="txtDisc" Text="{Binding Discount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"/>

                  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding itemSubDisplayList2}" x:Name="dgItemSub">

                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="item sub" Binding="{Binding ItemIdSub}"/>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="item sub code" Binding="{Binding ItemSubCode}"/>
                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>
             </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
          </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

I have two list or sources that I need to bind in this data grid. for item in `datagrid.column` and textbox `Discount` (in RowDetailsTemplate ) its using `itemsSource = itemDisplayList` meanwhile for item inside 'dgItemSub' its using itemsSource `itemSubDisplayList2`

the thing is I've this code at my code behind

```
 dgDisplay.ItemsSource = itemDisplayList;
 dgDisplay.ItemsSource = itemSubDisplayList2;
```

but it seem like I can't used both. only item that bind to `itemSubDisplayList2` works. but if I do not do this it doesn't show any output inside my datagrid.

I've try something like this

```
  <DataGrid Name="dgDisplay" ItemsSource="{Binding itemDisplayList}">

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding itemSubDisplayList2}" x:Name="dgItemSub">
```

without doing `dgDisplay.ItemsSource = itemDisplayList;` and `dgDisplay.ItemsSource = itemSubDisplayList2;` at code behind but it didn't work.

How can I bind from 2 itemsSource in this ?

or is there a way i can access `dgItemSub` from code behind. like I want to something like this

```
dgItemSub.ItemsSource = itemSubDisplayList2;
```

this is how i code the `itemDisplayList` and `itemSubDisplayList2` and I code this at code behind

```
       ItemDisplay itemDisplay = new ItemDisplay()
                    {
                        ItemCode = item.ItemCode,
                        ItemName = item.ItemName,
                        ItemPrice = item.ItemPrice,
                        Quantity = 1,
                    };

                    itemDisplayList.Add(itemDisplay);


                    foreach (var id in itemIds)
                    {
                        SimpleItem item2 = simpleItemBO.GetItemByItemId(id);
                        itemList.Add(item2);

                        ItemSubDisplay itemSubDisplay = new ItemSubDisplay();
                        itemSubDisplay.ItemIdSub = item2.ItemId;
                      itemSubDisplay.ItemSubCode = item2.ItemCode;
                        itemSubDisplayList.Add(itemSubDisplay);
                    }

                    itemSubDisplayList2.AddRange(itemSubDisplayList);
```

Comment: are u using mvvm? is this need to be done in mvvm?

Comment: yes I do use mvvm but I code `itemDisplayList`  and `itemSubDisplayList2` at my code behind

Comment: If u r setting a datacontext from outside u need to specify `<DataGrid x:Name="dgItemSub"  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.itemSubDisplayList2}" ` u need to use something like this

Comment: As it is present inside a Template.  if not working try to post the where u r setting DataContext

Comment: and also will this `itemSubDisplayList2` commom to all the rows from `itemDisplayList`

Comment: @Avinash I've updated my question with how the `itemSubDisplayList2` and `itemDisplayList` being code. and nope both does not have the same data and it completely from different entity model

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hello I check this code and here u have done some mistakes so i modified it
**Xaml**

```
 <DataGrid  Name="dgDisplay" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="dgItemCode" Width="100" Header="Barcode" Binding="{Binding ItemCode}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="dgItemName" Width="200" Header="Item Name" Binding="{Binding ItemName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="dgItemPrice" Width="100" Header="Item Price" Binding="{Binding ItemPrice, StringFormat=RM {0}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="dgQuantity" Width="150" Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate >
                <DataTemplate  x:Name="dtItemDisplay"  >
                    <StackPanel  Name="spItemDisplay2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" >
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="Discount: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <TextBox   x:Name="txtDisc" Text="{Binding Discount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"/>

                            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding itemSubDisplayList}" x:Name="dgItemSub" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  CanUserAddRows="False">

                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="item sub" Binding="{Binding ItemIdSub}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="item sub code" Binding="{Binding ItemSubCode}"/>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
```

**Code**

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
    
            public List<ItemDisplay> itemDisplayList { get; set; }
    
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                this.DataContext = this;
    
                itemDisplayList = new List<ItemDisplay>();
                ItemDisplay itemDisplay = new ItemDisplay()
                {
                    ItemCode = "1",
                    ItemName = "1",
                    ItemPrice = "1",
                    Quantity = "1",
                    itemSubDisplayList = new List<ItemSub>()
                };
                itemDisplay.itemSubDisplayList.Add(new ItemSub { ItemIdSub = "sa", ItemSubCode = "ran" });
                itemDisplayList.Add(itemDisplay);
    
                dgDisplay.ItemsSource = itemDisplayList;
    
            }


  public class ItemDisplay
    {
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public string ItemPrice { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public List<ItemSub> itemSubDisplayList { get; set; }
    }


    public class ItemSub
    {
        public string ItemIdSub { get; set; }
        public string ItemSubCode { get; set; }
    }
```

**output**
[image: Output ss]

Comment: I've try your code and its work. but I have one problem, as you can see above for `itemSubDisplayList` I have a foreach loop. how can I apply that loop ?

Comment: @newbie, as u said every row has different sub items so u need to take a list in u, r the main list as I have taken above and coming to changing for loop I can't help much its domain dependent need check the remaining code and we can make proper dession

Comment: @newbie it's just an example. filling the data is domain dependent

Comment: Thaaaank you so much ! you save my life :) its working fantastic !

Comment: I already found a solution for the foreach. Thanks again. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: may i know wt is the problem

Comment: I don't know why someone vote this as `unuseful` without any explaination while this code work for me

Comment: @newbie This is a terrible answer because it does not explain anything. There is only "*here u have done some mistakes*" without telling what exactly these errors are. Posting a bunch of code doesn't make a good answer, even if the code is exactly what you needed. Keep in mind that StackOverflow is a community and posts should be useful for all readers.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for that I will remember it next time.